# WPF Treeview literates a string type property and regards every single letter as an item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, mvvm-light

I'm using MvvmLight to manipulate a `treeview` control.The binding is OK,and my `Treeview` can get data from  its `ViewModel`.However,something weird happened.

In the `ViewModel`,I have a `string` type property:

```
private string foo;
public string Foo
{
    get { return foo; }
    set
    {
        if (foo== value)
            return;
        foo= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Foo");
    }
}
```

In the `ViewModel`'s Constructor,I initialized `Foo`:

```
Foo = "Marry has a little lamb";
```

In the `View`,I bind `Foo` to treeview:

```
<TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Foo}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="BurlyWood"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

I expected the treeview to show "Mary has a little lamb".But instead,it shows

```
M
a
r
r
...
```

Apparently,it has treated every single letter as an item.I've tried to change Foo's type to `ObservableCollection<string>`.Though it works,for some reason,I don't want to change Foo's type.What's the cause of this strange behavior,and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you're binding the `TreeView` to your property that is a `String`.
The tree expects a collection of some type, and finds a `string`. It thinks, hey, I know what `string` is ... it's a collection of `chars` ... and off he goes chopping marry and her poor lamb.

So, you either have to "box" your strings into a collection, or change your strategy :)

Edit:
some more info, in case someone else stumbles upon this:

From MSDN: [ItemsControl.ItemsSource Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

```
[BindableAttribute(true)]
public IEnumerable ItemsSource { get; set; }
```

And having some fun with it:

```
var an_int = 4;
var a_string = "poor poor marry";
int[] an_array = new int[3] {1,2,3};

if (an_int is IEnumerable)
    Console.WriteLine("you shouldn't see this");

if (a_string is IEnumerable)
    Console.WriteLine("you should see this, as IEnumerable char");

if (an_array is IEnumerable)
    Console.WriteLine("you should see this, as IEnumerable int");
```

Comment: I understand now,it seems that `ObservableCollection<T>` is a right option,thanks.

Comment: Added some more exapmles. You can also go with `ObservableCollection<string>` as a more specific one if you want ...